# Why am I unable to enter an input for my last scanf?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int yos;
char gen;
char qual;

printf("Enter your sex (M/F):\n");
scanf("%c", &gen);
printf("Enter your year(s) of service:\n");
scanf("%d", &yos);
printf("Enter your qualification (G/P):\n");
scanf("%c", &qual);

return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I am able to enter values for the first two scanf, but I cannot enter a value for the last scanf. Why is that happening?

Comment: Change `"%c"` to `" %c"` so it skips over the newline that ended the years of service.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is check the return value from each `scanf` call, which is the number of fields it successfully extracted.  In your case, you want it to be 1.  I suspect your `scanf` calls are consuming newlines where you don't expect it, so you should change the formats by adding a space at the front, which will cause it to consume white space.

Comment: @TomKarzes It worked! Thank you so much! Enjoy: https://youtu.be/qnkuBUAwfe0 !

Comment: @Barmar It worked! Thank you so much! Enjoy: https://youtu.be/qnkuBUAwfe0 !